# SQL: Collecting all people from a table while ignoring their paired ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I've got a table of people that looks like the following:

```
ID | Reference | Name         | LinkedID
1  | A001      | John Smith   | 2
2  | A002      | Jane Smith   | 1
3  | A003      | Joe Bloggs   | 5
5  | A004      | Janet Bloggs | 3
7  | A005      | Mary Sue     |
```

I'm trying to select all clients from this table but count all linked people as one person, so i'd get something that looks like this:

```
ID | Reference | Name         | LinkedID
1  | A001      | John Smith   | 2
3  | A003      | Joe Bloggs   | 5
7  | A005      | Mary Sue     |
```

Is this type of query possible?

Comment: yes, you can do it in a few different ways. Join to self and Group By would be a good start. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: I believe that linking such as 1 and 2 will cause problems.  Having an up and down relationship with one linking field... I just dont see how it could work.

Comment: @JoshAdams I've tried a join to self and group by, unless i'm not joining correctly i'm not getting any worthwhile results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns all records except those that appear in some **previous** LinkedId.

- 1 previuos LinkedId (none)
- 2 previous LinkedId (2) => rejected
- 3 previous LinkedId (2,1) => accepted
- 4 previous LinkedId (2,1,5) => accepted
  ....

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl t1
> where  ID not in (select LinkedID from tbl where ID < t1.ID)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Reference | Name       | LinkedID
> -: | :-------- | :--------- | -------:
>  1 | A001      | John Smith |        2
>  3 | A003      | Joe Bloggs |        5
>  7 | A005      | Mary Sue   |     null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da5b018cd63040acd25fadb9296ab9a8)*

Comment: Are you able to break it down a little? While it's working i'm a little unsure as to how it's all working.

Comment: I'm glad to help